# 3.5 VS 4.0 .NET Framework

Tags: c#, linq, frameworks

5 framework, not using relationship foreign key in database, and i wonder how 4.0 can improve this junk of code which i need to pass back the multiple object after multiple joins of tables.

```
  public IList<User> GetTutorByCourseId(int courseId)
    {
        IList<User> output = new List<User>();
        using (leDataContext db = new leDataContext())
        {
            try
            {
                var m = from c in db.Courses
                        join ct in db.CourseByTutors on c.Id equals ct.CourseId
                        join u in db.Users on ct.TutorId equals u.Id
                        where c.Id == courseId
                        select new
                        {
                            c, ct, u
                        };

                foreach (var result in m)
                {
                    User user = new User();
                    user.Id = result.u.Id;
                    user.Name = result.u.Name;
                    user.CourseTutor.Id = result.ct.Id;
                    user.Course.Name = result.c.Name;    
                    output.Add(user);
                }
                return output;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.Error(typeof(User), ex.ToString());
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

There are 3 objects being return to the caller in GUI. However, to do this i got to add the property of public CourseByTutors{get;set} and the public Course(get;set;) in the User class which i find that it will mess up my code.  In this case, how would 4.0 able to solve this? i read something about select tupel ..  ??

Comment: You can select a tuple, or at least dynamic type in 3.5, AFAIK.

Comment: Could you show me an example by converting my code above? i am actually deciding whether to convert to 4.0 or not..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though you don't have foreign keys in the database, there's no reason that you can't add relationships into your EF model.  This will help simplify the problem as you will not have to generate additional properties to store your child values; CourseTutor, CourseName etc..

Both 3.5 and 4.0 can help out here, although, in my experience this is much easier in 4.0.

Once the your code above might look something like:

```
var results = (from u in db.Users
        where u.Course.Id == courseId
        select u).ToList();
return results;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think keeping the relationships in the model is the right thing to do, but this won't really solve the problem.  When you do this you do get all the users in the course, but for each user you get all of their courses and all of the courses they tutor.  Ignoring that there probably isn't a direct course relationship (it's through one of tutor, instructor, or student), for each user you will get the collection of courses they tutor, not just the one course in question.  Figuring out which course is of interest from this may not be possible.  Better to use a specific model for the view, IMO.

Comment: If you are simply returning the data as a read only view, then why not consider using a stored procedure to flatten the query and return all the data to you in one simple query?  It all depends where your experience is and what technology you are happy working with.  If you do decide on using stored procedures then you have a few options; use the entity framework (4.0 is much easier) check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896279.aspx or create a dataset and add the stored procedure to it.  The latter is a breeze to do but perhaps will introduce something else to maintain.

Answer (score 3):

What about this (in 3.5)?

```
select new User
{
    Id = u.Id,
    Name = u.Name,
    CourseTutor = new CourseTutor {Id = ct.Id},
    Course = new Course {Name = c.Name}
};
return m.ToList();
```

EDIT: Replaced illegal `CourseTutor.Name` and `Course.Id` initializers. The corrected code will work, assuming that the constructor of `User` didn't do any fancy initialization of `CourseTutor` and `Course`.

Comment: +1. Incidentally ReSharper will provide some refactoring hints towards similar solutions.

Comment: thanks for the prompt reply. But i don think u are able to pass in that way since i am passing back the IList<User>? i got this error 'Invalid initializer member declarator' at the CourseTutor.Id = ct.Id

Comment: @TrueWill: +1 for promoting ReSharper. ;-) However, I suddenly became uncertain about whether this is what the OP was really asking for; it looks like he is more interested in removing the extra properties on `User`...

Comment: @belinq: It should work. A `from ... select` statement returns an `IQueryable<Type>`, where `Type` is the type of whatever you write after `select`. So my suggestion will first produce an `IQueryable<User>`, on which we call `ToList()` to get a `List<User>`, which implements `IList<User>` and can therefore be returned.

Comment: hi, i am actually wonder how 4.0 can shorten that junk of code. It  would be great if i don even have to put the extra properties in `User` class

Comment: @belinq: My bad; you can't initialize nested properties (`CourseTutor.Id` and `Course.Name`) like I showed. Let me think for a little while...

Comment: Null reference exception?  Unless, CourseTutor and Course are initialized in the User constructor -- which would seem odd.

Comment: @Aasmund: May i know when should i select new User, and when should i just select new {} ?

Comment: @tvanfosson: I assumed they were, because of what his code did - but my initial code had a syntax error anyway; fixed now.

Comment: @belinq: You should use `select new ExistingClass{}` when you have an existing class that "fits" the query result, and when you want to return a query result from a method. If you only want to use the query result internally in a method and you don't have a class that "fits" the result, you can use `select new{}` (it's called an _anonymous type_).

Comment: @Lasse - `IList<User>` -- which still leaves the problem of polluting the User entity with view data.  The only clean way to solve this is by using a view-specific class as I noted in my answer because you need to, at least, specify which `courseId` is of interest if you allow the entity model to contain its relationships or (as in this answer) add GUI-specific data to the entity model (for all views).  It's better to recognize that what you're producing is not a "user" but rather a model for the display to consume which contains a mixture of user and course data.

Comment: @belinq -- it's not junk because it's long, it's junk because you're corrupting your entity model by creating dependencies merely to support your display needs.  You intuitively recognize that your display and entity models are different -- thus your frustration -- but you need to take the next step of formalizing this by creating separate models for your display needs.

Comment: @tvanfosson: Thanks so much of this, i found it very make sense ` it's junk because you're corrupting your entity model by creating dependencies merely to support your display needs`. If i were to create relationship foreigh key in the database, then i would have save all this "junk" :) thanks again everyone for the exceleent suppport here.

Comment: @Aasmund Eldhuset: i have tried your code, but i think i got this error `{"Explicit construction of entity type 'le.DataModel.User' in query is not allowed."}` it seems like the error happen at here CourseTutor = new CourseTutor {Id = ct.Id},
    Course = new Course {Name = c.Name}

Comment: @belinq: It seems like Entity Framework (or whichever ORM you use) doesn't allow creation of entity objects inside a query. This problem will disappear if you follow @tvanfosson's advice to create a separate view model class for User.

Answer (score 0):

The way that I would normally handle this is to have a separate model from my data entities for the GUI that includes just the information that the GUI needs.  You could do this in 3.5 if you want.

```
public class TutorViewModel
{
     public IEnumerable<User> Tutors { get; set; }
     // the pair CourseId, UserId is the relation in CourseTutors so we only
     // need to keep it once, not once per user.
     public int CourseId { get; set; } 
     public string CourseName { get; set; }
}



public TutorViewModel GetTutorByCourseId(int courseId)
{
    var model = new TutorViewModel { CourseId = courseId };

    using (leDataContext db = new leDataContext())
    {
        try
        {
            model.CourseName = db.Courses
                                 .First( c => c.CourseId == courseId )
                                 .Name;
            model.Users = db.CourseByTutors
                            .Where( c => c.Id == courseId )
                            .Join( db.Users,
                                   c => c.TutorId,
                                   u => u.Id,
                                   (c,u) => u );

            return model;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Error(typeof(User), ex.ToString());
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```